# react native rendering a list of buttons can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, rendering, setstate

I'm trying to make a list of buttons based on the input from user input type is an array of options like so `multipleOptions = ['1', '2', '3']` then we loop through each option to show a Button can't figure out why it's not working here's my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

const InputButton = (multipleOptions, likertScale, onPress) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  if (likertScale) {
    setOptions([...new Array(likertScale).keys()].map((i) => i));
  } else if (multipleOptions) setOptions(multipleOptions);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {options ? (
        options.map((option, i) => (
          <View style={[styles.button]} key={`${i}`}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(option)}>
              <Text>{option}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))
      ) : (
        <Text>no options</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <InputButton multipleOptions={['1', '2','3']} />
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 3,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#EEF6FA',
    minHeight: 72,
    borderRadius: 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

the error message is

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

or sometimes this

```
options.map is not a function
TypeError: options.map is not a function
    at InputButton
```

(All kind of optimisations are welcome)
Thanks in Advance guys.

code demo https://snack.expo.io/@mansouriala/dac832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put set state in every re-render so you get a loop. So you have two options use useEffect to just set state one time or set the first state directly.
https://snack.expo.io/ZvLQM9FEF

```
const InputButton = ({multipleOptions, likertScale, onPress}) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(likertScale?[...new Array(likertScale).keys()].map((i) => i):[ ...multipleOptions]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {options ? (
        options.map((option, i) => (
          <View style={[styles.button]} key={`${i}`}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(option)}>
              <Text>{option}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))
      ) : (
        <Text>no options</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues here.

The first, which leads to `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` is because you're calling `setOptions` at each render, which triggers another render, etc… This is infinite loop, because when you're setting a state, React re-renders the component. To avoid that, you have to wrap your expression with `useEffect` and the correct dependencies.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (likertScale) {
    setOptions([...new Array(likertScale).keys()].map((i) => i));
  } else if (multipleOptions) {
    setOptions(multipleOptions);
  }, [multipleOptions, likertScale]);
```

This way, this expression would only run when `multipleOptions` or `likertScale` change.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

The other problem is that `InputButton` props argument is wrong: you forgot the props destructuring. It should be `const InputButton = ({ multipleOptions, likertScale, onPress }) => { /* body function */ }`.

Finally, it's a bad practice to use an array index as a `key` prop, because array order could change. You should use a stable key, like the option value `key={option}`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys